# .NET Core 2.0 Localization across projects

Tags: .net-core, localization

I have 2 projects:
1. WebApi
2. Common

The resource files are in the WebApi, and the WebApi is calling the Common. However, the Common needs to get the string from the resource file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using IStringLocalizerFactory to create the IStringLocalizer. Here is an example of the code that solved my problem:

`var assemblyName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
return _localizerFactory.Create("ExceptionResource", assemblyName);`

Answer (score 0):

You make a resource file(s) in your business logic, **you're a definitely not going to create a dependency between your business logic-project and your web-project** in  order to be able to access your Localization resources.

The key issue, as you wrote was:

> "(...) resolve it using IStringLocalizerFactory to create the
> IStringLocalizer".

A real life example a this could be

[image: example]

You can do it like you have written and which is similar to what is in the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request

Here's an example of Damien Bod from his short manual

https://damienbod.com/2017/11/01/shared-localization-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

u

```
sing Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System.Reflection;
 
namespace AspNetCoreMvcSharedLocalization.Resources
{
    public class LocService
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
 
        public LocService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var type = typeof(SharedResource);
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
        }
 
        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
        {
            return _localizer[key];
        }
    }
}
```

You don't actually need a dummy class, you could also do it like:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
```

namespace ….Business.LocalizationService

```
{
    public interface ILocalizationMiddleware
    {
        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string keyForResourceTable);
    }
}

using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;
using System.Reflection;
```

namespace ….Business.LocalizationService

```
{
    public class LocalizationMiddleware : ILocalizationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;

        public LocalizationMiddleware(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName);
        }

        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedString(string keyForResourceTable) { return localizer[keyForResourceTable]; }
    }
}
```